# Refresh data in ListFragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment

I want to get data from php, then show in listview. But I do not know not to tell the listview update the data I have got for php. I have try to use notifyDataSetChanged();, but I do know where should it put.

```
public class List_View extends ListFragment{
    private String result;
    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
    final String uri = "http://localhost/userinfo.php";

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, container, false);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
        return rootView;
    }

    class sendPostRunnable implements Runnable{
        @Override
        public void run(){
            result = sendPostDataToInternet();
            String temp = "Not result.";

            try {
                JSONTokener jsonTokener = new JSONTokener(result); 
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonTokener.nextValue(); 
                JSONArray jarray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("response");
                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) { 
                    temp = "";
                    JSONObject jobject = jarray.getJSONObject(i); 
                    temp += "name: "+jobject.getString("name")+"\n"; 
                    temp += "email: "+jobject.getString("email"); 
                    items.add(temp);
                    temp = "";

                } 
                if(jarray.length() < 1){
                    items.add(temp);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }

    private String sendPostDataToInternet(){

        HttpPost httpRequest = new HttpPost(uri);
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", "u1"));
        try{

            httpRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(httpRequest);

            if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){
                String strResult = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
                return strResult;
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not get the data from your server first and then populate the list after you have received the data?  This way you will not have to use notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: I'm not sure if into a Runnable class you can add more items without a FC.
I think that you must declare an Handler instance and send your array via Message. This allow send your data from secondary thread to your GUI thread. So first you add your items to adapter and then use notifyDatasetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

You should collect all arrived data in other collection (other than used in list adapter) in separate thread and then replace the list colletion source and right after than you should call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

```
        public class List_View extends ListFragment{
            private String result;
            private ListView listView;
    protected List newData;
    protected ArrayAdapter listAdapter;
            private ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
            final String uri = "http://localhost/userinfo.php";

            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, container, false);
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
                setListAdapter(listAdapter );
                return rootView;
            }

            class sendPostRunnable implements Runnable{
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    result = sendPostDataToInternet();
                    String temp = "Not result.";

// a new collection to fill from response
newData = new ArrayList<String>();
                    try {
                        JSONTokener jsonTokener = new JSONTokener(result); 
                        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonTokener.nextValue(); 
                        JSONArray jarray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("response");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) { 
                            temp = "";
                            JSONObject jobject = jarray.getJSONObject(i); 
                            temp += "name: "+jobject.getString("name")+"\n"; 
                            temp += "email: "+jobject.getString("email"); 
    //here you should create a corresponding object from JSON
    // and add it to newData List
                            newData .add(temp);
                            temp = "";

                        } 
                        if(jarray.length() < 1){
                            items.add(temp);
                        }
    // here you will have a newData List filled so you should
    // replace or add data from this List to ListView's used
    items.add(newData);
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            }

            private String sendPostDataToInternet(){

                HttpPost httpRequest = new HttpPost(uri);
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", "u1"));
                try{

                    httpRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(httpRequest);

                    if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){
                        String strResult = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
                        return strResult;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
```